# Style brand and text in navbar

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a personal website [template](https://codepen.io/adhysatya/pen/zJrqqr) but I can't style the image and the text in the navbar.

1. I want to fix the aspect ratio of the image to center the `navbar`, so independently from the height of the navbar, the image will always look the same.
2. I want to center the text vertically
3. Make `CONTACT` into `Contact`

I'm not using boostrap or other frameworks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the `flex` box property, this is really useful. [Here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is some documentation on the subject and [here](https://codepen.io/Baboo_/pen/NLxrjx) is an example on how to build the layout you want using flex box.

Comment: the lower case doesn't work on the example you shared

Comment: Thanks! How do I make the C in contact capitalized?

Comment: Use `text-transform: capitalize` instead of `text-transform: lowercase`

Answer (score 0):

1.- I didn't understand this one, you want to 'fix the ratio' but the ratio is already fixed and you can change the size of it using percentage on `height` and `width`.

2.- Add the next lines to the `navbar` css:

```css
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

that will center vertically all the elements in your navbar, including the image.

3.- Try this:

```css
.navbar li:last-child a {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

or `text-transform: capitalize` if you want the first letter capitalized.